# UI instance is not available when running unit tests

Tags: vaadin

I am going through the Vaadin tutorial but am trying to go through it using gradle instead of maven and have got to the 'Creating and running unit tests for simple UI logic' section.

In this section there are two tests.

One involving a simple Java object and the other involving the form being used. The first runs but he second gives me the above error.

I suspect that maven has a plugin that is used to start the ui in this case? Has anyone completed the tutorial in gradle instead of maven? My build.gradle is as follows.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.8'
    id 'com.vaadin' version '0.14.6.0'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.altaavionics'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('snippetsDir', file("build/generated-snippets"))
    set('vaadinVersion', "14.6.4")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    //VAADIN
    implementation ('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter')
    //TESTING
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-testbench'
    testImplementation 'io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:3.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine'

//  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
//  testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

asciidoctor {
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    dependsOn test
}
```

My test class are the same as the tutorial but here it is

```
package com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.views.list;

import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.entity.Company;
import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.entity.Contact;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class ContactFormTest {
    private List<Company> companies;
    private Contact marcUsher;
    private Company company1;
    private Company company2;

    @Before
    public void setupData() {
        companies = new ArrayList<>();
        company1 = new Company("Vaadin Ltd");
        company2 = new Company("IT Mill");
        companies.add(company1);
        companies.add(company2);

        marcUsher = new Contact();
        marcUsher.setFirstName("Marc");
        marcUsher.setLastName("Usher");
        marcUsher.setEmail("marc@usher.com");
        marcUsher.setStatus(Contact.Status.NotContacted);
        marcUsher.setCompany(company2);
    }

    @Test
    public void formFieldsPopulated() {
        ContactForm form = new ContactForm(companies);
        form.setContact(marcUsher);
        Assert.assertEquals("Marc", form.firstName.getValue());
        Assert.assertEquals("Usher", form.lastName.getValue());
        Assert.assertEquals("marc@usher.com", form.email.getValue());
        Assert.assertEquals(company2, form.company.getValue());
        Assert.assertEquals(Contact.Status.NotContacted, form.status.getValue());
    }

    @Test
        public void saveEventHasCorrectValues() {
            ContactForm form = new ContactForm(companies);
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            form.setContact(contact);

            form.firstName.setValue("John");
            form.lastName.setValue("Doe");
            form.company.setValue(company1);
            form.email.setValue("john@doe.com");
            form.status.setValue(Contact.Status.Customer);

            AtomicReference<Contact> savedContactRef = new AtomicReference<>(null);
            form.addListener(ContactForm.SaveEvent.class, e -> {
                savedContactRef.set(e.getContact());
            });
            form.save.click();
            Contact savedContact = savedContactRef.get();

            Assert.assertEquals("John", savedContact.getFirstName());
            Assert.assertEquals("Doe", savedContact.getLastName());
            Assert.assertEquals("john@doe.com", savedContact.getEmail());
            Assert.assertEquals(company1, savedContact.getCompany());
            Assert.assertEquals(Contact.Status.Customer, savedContact.getStatus());
        }

}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? Can you please shwo the code?

Comment: Please specify your Vaadin version and share your actual test code.

Answer (score 1):

since both the exception stack trace and the test code is missing, I can only guess. Usually you test your app by running it (by using a special Gradle plugin), then accessing the server via Selenium/TestBench. However, this approach is used for integration/system testing, and you explicitly mentioned unit tests. For those, a bit of setup is needed otherwise `UI.getCurrent()` will return null.

To perform this setup easily, please take a look at https://github.com/mvysny/karibu-testing . There's a ton of documentation including Gradle-based example projects.